# Multi site access with a single i.p address

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, admin, multistore, administration

I followed the steps on [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) tutorial to setup my multi-domain site, and its working fine, but now i want to setup my another site which has multi sites but currently I have single i.p address to access them all. I tried different tricks in httpd.conf, .htaccess and also changed site address in admin panel at site level but it did not work. How I can make them working with single ip address?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

> My httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 1.2.3.4/a
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 1.2.3.4/b
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess file

```
 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4/a MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_a
 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_a
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4 MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4/b MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_b
 SetEnvIf Host 1.2.3.4/b MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4/b MAGE_RUN_CODE=site_b
 SetEnvIf Host ^1.2.3.4/b MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I tried ips like `1\.2\.3\.4` in .htaccess as well.

I also changed the site unsecure/secure urls to 1.2.3.4/a and 1.2.3.4/b but no gain.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you can handle the redirect in index.php for a single IP. However you will need to consider the SSL implications for just having a single IP. One option is to get a SANs SSL...

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "www.website1.com"){
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "website1code";
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "website";
}

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "www.website2.eu"){
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "website2code";
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "website";
}


/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: I do have only i.p for now, do not have any domain name mapped on that i.p. would it work the same way for the i.p?